# Solving an asymptotic equivalence for x

Tags: asymptotics

This might be a very dumb question, but I have googled around and looked in asymptotic analysis reference texts and cannot seem to find what I am looking for. So here we go:

Suppose I know that there exists some $x$ such that $xn \sim n^2$ as $n \to \infty$. Can I conclude that $x \sim n$?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I suppose $x$ is an expression depending on $n$?

Comment: There are various equivalence relations that you might have in mind.  In any case a proof will proceed (perhaps indirectly) from the definition of that equivalence, so stating it in the Question is certainly expeditious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because *equivalence* is compatible with multiplication, so
$$xn\sim n^2\quad\text{and}\quad \frac1n\sim\frac1n\quad\text{imply}\quad xn\cdot \frac1n=x\sim n^2\frac1n=n.$$

Comment: Ah, thank you. Is there a similar thing I can do for an equation like $x^2 - nx \sim n^2$ — again with $n$ arbitrary large and $x = x(n)$?

Comment: I'm afraid not (I don't know the context), as equivalence is not compatible with addition nor subtraction.

Comment: For that you would use the method of dominant balance @H.Löw